# invalid datetime format: insert date/time into Access from Java

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I want to insert a datetime value to Access, but I get this error:

> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.4 data exception: invalid datetime format

Here is the code :

```
private void txtsubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    SimpleDateFormat A = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Peminjaman P= new Peminjaman(setIDTrans(),txtid.getText(),A.format(txttglpinjam.getDate()),A.format(txttglkembali.getDate()),txtplat.getText(),txtnama.getText(),txtdriver.getText());
    c.InsertPeminjamanD(P);
```

Comment: You might try using `#17/04/2004#` instead of `17/04/2004` as date string as shown at http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/format.php. If that solves your problem, report back, then I make my comment an answer for you to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message indicates that your `InsertPeminjamanD` method is ultimately trying to do something like

```sql
INSERT INTO Table1 (DateTimeField) VALUES ('31/05/2016')
```

and that won't work for two reasons:

1. UCanAccess expects date literals to be enclosed in hash marks (`#`), and
2. UCanAccess normally expects `xx/yy/zzzz` date literals to be `MM/dd/yyyy`, not `dd/MM/yyyy`.

So, the above query will work if it is rearranged as ...

```sql
INSERT INTO Table1 (DateTimeField) VALUES (#05/31/2016#)
```

... although it really would be better to use a PreparedStatement and pass it a proper date value:

```java
String sql = "INSERT INTO Table1 (DateTimeField) VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2016-05-31"));
ps.executeUpdate();
```